# How to eagerly load ion-modal in Angular 10

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

Just to be clear, I don't believe this issue is at all related to routing lazy-loading because this issue is in a bootstrapped component where this is failing to run as expected.

I have an ion-modal that is triggered from the base app.component for when no network is detected. I need to ensure that the ion-modal scripts are available after the initial payload is sent; however, when I load the app then turn off the network in the network debugger tab it is lazy-loading ion-modal.
`vendor.js:41664 ChunkLoadError: Loading chunk 20 failed.`

The script being referenced has the following in its webpack comments and appears to be entirely ion-modal code.
`./node_modules/@ionic/core/dist/esm/ion-modal.entry.js`

If I trigger a modal to show then hide, the chunk is successfully loaded and the following network error modal works as expected when triggered in the network debugger. When I try to search for articles around eager loading it's always about routing and that is *not* what I am looking for here.

Comment: This is the current solution which is less-than-ideal. The following is placed in app.component.html: ```<ion-modal style="display:none;"></ion-modal>```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Closing the loop on this. In ionic v4.x, this isn't possible as it appears the overlay components are registered at runtime. While `<ion-modal style="display:none;">` can be used with JIT-compiled templates to preload the scripts where needed, it will fail when used with AOT-compiled templates. So the solution for now is to programmatically present then dismiss a modal during the bootstrap process or as early as can be done after IonicModule is available.

```
  // Call this somewhere early where IonicModule has been imported, we are doing it in the app.component.ts constructor in our example
  async preloadModal() {
    let tempModal = await this.modalController.create({
      animated: false, // this should prevent it from being visible
      swipeToClose: false, // disable interaction to prevent unexpected behavior
      backdropDismiss: false, // disable interaction to prevent unexpected behavior
      showBackdrop: false, // minimize changes to UI
      keyboardClose: false, // minimize side-effects
      component: MyModalComponent, // Your custom modal component likely won't render, be sure to preload any related assets inside the index.html <head> tags
      componentProps: {
        // your component props, if needed
      }
    });
    await tempModal.present();
    await tempModal.dismiss();
  }
```

[Related github issue](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/issues/20117)

Answer (score 0):

I used another alternative:

```
    modal:any;

    async hiddenModal() {
      const modal = await this.modalCtrl.create({
        component: EditorComponent
      });
      modal.hidden=true;
      modal.onDidDismiss().then(() => {
        this.modal=null;
      });
      await modal.present();
      this.modal = modal;
    }

    async showModal() {
      if(this.modal)
        this.modal.hidden=false;
      else {
        const modal = await this.modalCtrl.create({
          component: EditorComponent,
        });
        modal.onDidDismiss().then(() => {
          this.modal = null;
        });
        await modal.present();
        this.modal = modal;
      }
    }
```